# Could not get status from metro bundler

Tags: react-native, expo, metro-bundler

I keep getting the same error message when I run `expo start`. It keeps saying

> Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001
> Connecting to Metro bundler failed.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled `expo-cli`
I've uninstalled and reinstalled `node`
I've tried `expo start -c`

Nothing worked

This is the full error message

```
C:\Users\smiz\Desktop\dev\react-native\cleaningservices>expo start  
Starting project at C:\Users\smiz\Desktop\dev\react-native\cleaningservices  
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002  
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)  
Could not get status from Metro bundler. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:19001  
Connecting to Metro bundler failed.  
Error: Connecting to Metro bundler failed.  
    at _waitForRunningAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@58.0.19\src\Project.ts:1268:11)  
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)  
    at startReactNativeServerAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@58.0.19\src\Project.ts:1612:3)  
    at Object.startAsync (C:\@expo\xdl@58.0.19\src\Project.ts:1985:5)  
    at action (C:\Users\Stephen Murya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands     \start.ts:163:3)  
    at C:\Users\Stephen Murya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:330:16
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Stephen Murya\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:332:7)
```

I have run this project in the past using `expo`. I don't know why this all started.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this before posting this question, but I left it here for anyone this might help.

Run `npm clean --force`, and restart expo. I would also advice to restart your device(s)